# Generating function for Weyl-ordered spin correlation functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, lie-algebra, phase-space, wigner-transform

Consider the standard 2-dimensional phase space: $[\hat{x},\hat{p}] = \mathrm{i}$. Upon taking the Wigner transform of the density matrix $\hat{\rho}$,

\begin{equation}
W(x,p) = \int\mathrm{d}y\, \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} p y}\,\langle x + y/2\rvert\, \hat{\rho}\, \lvert x - y/2\rangle\,,
\end{equation}

we end up with the Wigner function $W(x,p)$. Its corresponding characteristic function,
\begin{equation}
\chi(j,k) = \int\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}p\, W(x,p) \exp(j x + k p) = \mathrm{Tr}\left[\hat{\rho} \exp\left(j\hat{x} + k \hat{p}\right)\right],
\end{equation}
is known to generate symmetric (or Weyl) ordered correlation functions. This can be easily translated to the language of creation/annihilation operators and coherent states. The generator there would be given by
\begin{equation}
\chi_s(\lambda,\lambda^{*}) = \mathrm{Tr}\left[\hat{\rho}\exp\left(\lambda\hat{a}^{\dagger} - \lambda^{*}\hat{a}\right)\right] \exp\left(s|\lambda|^2/2\right),
\end{equation}
where $s=1$, $s=0$, and $s=-1$ correspond to normal, symmetric, and anti-normal orderings, respectively.

My question is, what would be the corresponding expression for the generator of Weyl-ordered spin correlation functions, with $[\hat{L}_i,\hat{L}_j] = \mathrm{i}\varepsilon_{ijk}\hat{L}_k$? I.e., I would like to have an object $\chi(\mathbf{j})$ such that, e.g.,
\begin{equation}
\partial_{j_x}\partial_{j_y}\partial_{j_z} \chi(\mathbf{j})\lvert_{\mathbf{j}=0} = \frac{1}{6}\left(\langle\hat{L}_x \hat{L}_y \hat{L}_z\rangle + \langle\hat{L}_x \hat{L}_z \hat{L}_y \rangle + \langle\hat{L}_y \hat{L}_x \hat{L}_z \rangle + \langle\hat{L}_y \hat{L}_z \hat{L}_x \rangle + \langle\hat{L}_z \hat{L}_x \hat{L}_y \rangle + \langle\hat{L}_z \hat{L}_y \hat{L}_x \rangle\right).
\end{equation}

I naively expected it to be

\begin{equation}
\chi(\mathbf{j})
=
\mathrm{Tr}\left[\hat{\rho} \exp\left(\mathbf{j}\cdot \hat{\mathbf{L}}\right)\right]
=
\mathrm{Tr}\left[\hat{\rho} \exp\left(j_x\hat{L}_x + j_y\hat{L}_y + j_z\hat{L}_z\right)\right],
\end{equation}
but then I checked it for the fundamental representation case using the Rodrigues' formula to compute the exponential part, and realized that it could not be the generating function I was looking for.

I went through a lot of literature on the subject, where the authors would usually discuss the construction of a suitable Wigner function (or sometimes also Husimi and Sudarshan-Glauber). The closest I could find was

1. C. Chandler, L. Cohen, C. Lee, M. Scully & K. Wódkiewicz, [Found. Phys. **22**, 867 (1992)](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01889685).
2. R.P. Rundle, M.J. Everitt, [Adv. Quantum Technol., **4**, 2100016 (2021)](https://doi.org/10.1002/qute.202100016).

But even there I couldn't find the answer.

To summarize:

1. How does the generating function $\chi(\mathbf{j})$ for Weyl ordered $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ spin correlation functions look like? Specifically, for the fundamental representation $j=1$ (if the answer somehow depends on the representation).
2. How is $\chi(\mathbf{j})$ related to the $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ Wigner quasiprobability distribution? Is there a simple connection similar to the one between $W(x,p)$ and $\chi(j,k)$?

Comment: There isn't necessarily one unique way of generalizing Wigner functions to SU(2) (maybe try some of [these papers](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=wigner+function+su%282%29&btnG=))

Comment: Could try this [recent article](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.3.033134) for context. It's a version for discrete Wigner functions on the sphere, originated (as far as I recall) [here](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.63.012105)

Comment: @QuantumMechanic I have seen both of these papers. But as I said, similar to other articles I could find, neither of them addresses the question of the generating functional for Weyl-ordered correlation functions (which is my main question).

Comment: [Amiet & Weigert](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.63.012102).

Comment: @CosmasZachos again, they discuss the Wigner function for a spin and all that, but there's no mentioning of correlation functions, generators thereof, etc. Which of the expression in the paper would correspond to $\chi(\mathbf{j})$ in the original post?

Comment: @CosmasZachos yes, I didn't prove it, but I wasn't claiming it either, to be honest. I merely said "here's how it works for the canonically conjugate variables, is there anything similar for the spin case?" I was hoping that perhaps people had already considered this problem. Also, I am not even insisting on having $\chi(\mathbf{j})$ expressed as the Fourier transform of the Weyl transform of some density matrix (though it would be nice). I would be okay with having the expression $\chi(\mathbf{j}) = \mathrm{Tr}[\hat{\rho} \ldots ]$ if only I knew what's behind the $\ldots$

Comment: For the spin 1/2 case the trilinears' expectation value, completely symmetric under interchange of any two Ls, vanishes identically.

Comment: For the spin 1 case, however, I'm not sure what you mean: The Rodrigues formula yields zero, and your expectation value is 0.  So, 0=0 is certainly consistent with your symmetrized $\hat L$s exponential generating function. This is how combinatorics work. I fear you are confusing yourself with an excess of Wigner -Weyl formalism, when all you need is computing the generic expectation through [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Higher_spins)....

Comment: @CosmasZachos yes, I am well aware that due to the structure of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ algebra, a lot of higher order symmetric correlations will either vanish or at the very least reduce to lower order correlators. But I am not interested in $\chi(\mathbf{j})$ for practical reasons of computing said correlation functions. I am simply interested in how would the function that formally generates such symmetricly ordered correlation functions for spins would look like.

Comment: Your do understand, however, you have ***not*** excluded your naive exponential generating function formula. I'm not sure how you thought the Rodrigues formula and [its cousins](https://www.emis.de/journals/SIGMA/2014/084/) excluded it...

Comment: @CosmasZachos regarding the Rodrgues' formula, I meant the following. Let's say I want to compute $\left\langle \hat{L}_z^3\right\rangle$. By assumption, this should be given by $\partial_{l_z}^3 \chi(\mathbf{j})\rvert_{\mathbf{j}=0}$. However, according to the Rodrigues' formula, $\chi(\mathbf{j}) = \mathrm{Tr}\left[\hat{\rho} \exp\left(\mathbf{j} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{L}}\right)\right]$ would be quadratic in $\mathbf{j}$ in the fundamental representation. Therefore, such $\chi(\mathbf{j})$ definitely cannot generate symmetrically ordered spin correlation functions. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Sorry, I of course was wrong regarding the "at most quadratic in $\mathbf{j}$"... Still, I tried to check it explicitly for $\partial_{j_z}^3 \chi(\mathbf{j})\rvert_{\mathbf{j}=0}$ and it gave me$ \left\langle\hat{L}_z\right\rangle$, not $\left\langle\hat{L}_z^3\right\rangle$. Could it be that I simply messed up some calculations/code in the CAS?

Comment: In this representation, they are the same. See pseudo-answer communication....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "naive" conjecture is spot on!

To avoid an interminable chat, I am abusing the answer format to at least illustrate how to read/use the Rodrigues formula. Since the W-W formalism only serves to confuse you, let us merely study the generating function
$$
G=\langle e^{i(x\hat L _x + y \hat L_y + z \hat L_z)}\rangle 
$$
where the conjugate parameters are chosen to be **r** = *(x,y,z)* for simplicity, nothing to do with Cartesian space coordinates.

The Rodrigues rotation formula, then, simply amounts to
$$
e^{i{\mathbf r} \cdot {\mathbf L}}= {\mathbb I} + i {\mathbf r} \cdot {\mathbf L} \frac{\sin |{\mathbf r} | }{|{\mathbf r} |}  -( {\mathbf r} \cdot {\mathbf L} )^2\frac{\cos |{\mathbf r} |-1 }{{\mathbf r} ^2} ~~~.
$$

It is then evident that $\partial_x \partial_y\partial_z G |_{{\mathbf r}=0}$  vanishes just like your trilinear expectation value does, by direct calculation. (Needless to say, the spin 1/2 expression vanishes by inspection.)

To get $\langle L_z^3\rangle$, you don't even need the Rodrigues formula
which uses the basic Hamilton-Cayley property of the spin 1 representation,
$L_z^3=L_z$: this is the reason Rodrigues for it terminates at the quadratic term!  You note that setting $x=y=0$ *before* differentiation
won't make a difference, so, trivially,
$$
\partial_z^3  \langle e^{zL_z^3}\rangle |_{z=0}= \langle L_z^3\rangle.
$$

You may do this to the Rodrigues formula and find the same...

---

*Edit in response to comment question*

> 1. Does this G generate symmetric spin correlators?

Yes, indeed, absolutely, this *G* is symmetric w.r.t. the three elements in the exponent, and obeys the same combinatoric logic as Weyl ordering, for the same reasons.  It is a function of *x,y* and *z*. For instance, look at the term cubic in such parameters,
$$
\langle (x\hat L_x +y\hat L_y +z \hat L_z) ^3\rangle.
$$
it is manifestly symmetric, and enforces/defines what you analogize to Weyl ordering. For example, isolate the term proportional to *xyz*. It is necessarily symmetric in the three $\hat L$s. So your "naive"  expectation is correct and unique!

This property holds for arbitrary operators in the exponent. For the Spin operators you considered, the trilinear happens to vanish in the spin 1/2 and 1 representation.  It doesn't seem to do that in higher spin reps...

In any case, having resolved 1., your 2. is a completely independent question, namely the triple Fourier transform of that exponential. I don't see any deep connections to a density matrix, and thus a Wigner function, but take a look at [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1088/1751-8121/50/32/323001).

Comment: Many thanks! I think I was using the Rodrigues' formula a bit frivolously, which ultimately led to silly and borderline embarrassing mistakes. I still wonder, though:

1. Does this G generate symmetric spin correlators? I am planning to investigate it more carefully again myself (without resorting to CAS now), but maybe it's self-evident that it is/is not a generator of such 'Weyl ordered' correlators?

2. If so, does it have any simple connection to the $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ Wigner function, akin to the one that can be found in the mentioned papers? A la $W(x,p) \leftrightarrow \chi(j,k)$.

Comment: I now realized what was the source of my confusion regarding the Rodrgues' formula result. I didn't know that the latter employed the Hamilton-Cayley property of the generators. That's why I was baffled when I saw $\hat{L}_z$ instead of $\hat{L}_z^3$, etc. But now I am pretty convinced that my "naive guess" was indeed the right one! As for the paper, unfortunately, my university does not have an agreement with IOP Publishing, so I guess I'll have to actually go to the library to have an access to the publication... But  you are right that that's a completely different question.